# Str.contains in python pandas also flags blank

Tags: python, string, pandas, contains

For the following df (please note that the df I am working with is read in raw data imported from a txt file and not the below df created in python for this example)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['12374' ,'19352','21014','2619','2621','9566','9686','61319','68086','69239','69353', '69373','69491','69535','69582','69691','174572','174637','174646','175286','175390'], 
                   'Category': [' ', ' ', ' ', '???? ?????','? ?',' ','?? ?',' ',' ',' ','?? ?',' ','? ?','???? ????? ??? ','? ?','?? ?','A','A','B','B','C']})
```

I am trying to flag, where users denoted a category as question mark. It does work and it marks the flag for all rows with a question mark. But it also adds the the Y flag to rows which are blank in that column.

```
df['?_Flag'] = np.where(df['Category'].str.contains("\?"), 'Y', '')
```

Do I need to use match instead?

This is the dataframe I get:

```
ID      Category    ?_Flag
12374                  Y
19352                  Y
21014                  Y
2619    ???? ?????     Y
2621    ? ?            Y
9566                   Y
9686    ?? ?           Y
61319                  Y
68086                  Y
69239                  Y
69353   ?? ?           Y
69373                  Y
69491   ? ?            Y
69535   ???? ????? ??? Y
69582   ? ?            Y
69691   ?? ?           Y
174572   A
174637   A
174646   B
175286   B
175390   C
```

Could it be related to the datatype?

```
df.info()

First_Name_E  197357 non-null object
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Second @juanpa.arrivillaga's comment.  I don't see why your answer won't work as is.  We need to see sample data where you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: also to add, this person seems to not be putting much effort in to their own project seeing as they have asked 5 questions regarding this df in the last ~2 hours. we are happy to help, but not do your whole task for you, how do you plan to learn?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy; this is not a productive comment; I admit that I am very new to strings and regex and I am sorry if I have many basic questions; but I am working very hard on learning it as fast as possible and have been working a lot on my project and the reason I asked so many questions in the last 2 hours is because I summarized all the roadblocks I head, where I couldn't find a workaround or explanation in the python documentation or previous stackoverflow answers

Comment: @jeangelj, i [can't reproduce it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43056545/5741205)...

Comment: @MaxU thank you very much for trying, it must be related to the raw data then; I'm trying workaround to add a 0 where there is no value, maybe this will work

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue using Pandas 0.19.2:

```
In [16]: df['?_Flag'] = np.where(df['Category'].str.contains("\?"), 'Y', '')

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
        ID        Category ?_Flag
0
1    19352
2    21014
3     2619      ???? ?????      Y
4     2621             ? ?      Y
5     9566
6     9686            ?? ?      Y
7    61319
8    68086
9    69239
10   69353            ?? ?      Y
11   69373
12   69491             ? ?      Y
13   69535  ???? ????? ???      Y
14   69582             ? ?      Y
15   69691            ?? ?      Y
16  174572               A
17  174637               A
18  174646               B
19  175286               B
20  175390               C
```

Comment: Curios: why would using regex flag blank columns?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, i've added an explanation into my answer - please check

Comment: Right, but they've used an escape sequence, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thank you both, it must be somehow related to the raw data. I checked the fields both within the python dataframe and the raw data and they are blank - I am working on a workaround to add a 0 for blanks, so maybe this way the flag won't think it's a question mark

Answer (score 0):

```
df['?_Flag'] = np.where(df['Category'].str.contains("\?", na=False), 'Y', '')
```

`"na=False"` will give the correct result